# Unable to install package shiny on R 3.0.2

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I am using Win64 and am unable to install the 'shiny' package on R. When trying to install, the following message is populated. Can someone please put me in the right track or am I missing something really stupid here?

```
> install.packages("shiny")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ayan/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") : unable to resolve 'cran.r-project.org'
2: package ‘shiny’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

I tried using India, Cloud(0) as the CRAN mirror

contents of ui.R file:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

# Application title
 headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", 
            "Number of observations:", 
            min = 1,
            max = 1000, 
            value = 500)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
))
```

contents of server.R file:

```
    library(shiny)

    # Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a plot of the distribution. The expression
  # is wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically 
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot 
  #
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
        dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
        hist(dist)
      })
    })
```

Also I was facing problem installing the package 'holdOut' for classification problem. This is what it shows:

```
> install.packages("holdOut")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ayan/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘holdOut’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

Are these 2 problems related?

Comment: ok...have managed to install the package somehow but am stuck in the next stage. This is what I have done: 1. created a folder called "shinytest" in my Documents folder which is my working directory for R  2.I then have both R files ui.R and server.R in them. When i type in :

Comment: >library(shiny) and then >runApp("shinytest") R suddenly exits. Any idea?

Comment: Without code ... no idea.

Comment: contents of ui.R file:

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", 
                "Number of observations:", 
                min = 1,
                max = 1000, 
                value = 500)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
))

Comment: contents of server.R file:

    library(shiny)

    # Define server logic required to generate and plot a random distribution
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a plot of the distribution. The expression
  # is wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically 
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot 
  #
      output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
        dist <- rnorm(input$obs)
        hist(dist)
      })
    })

Comment: Both these files contents are copied on a text editor and saved as R files. Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: Can you post these as code in your question (i.e., edit your question). It is not readable as a comment.

Comment: will remember the tip

Comment: What happens when you put the following into R: require(shiny); runExample("01_hello")

Comment: "R for GUI frontend has stopped working" followed by the option to "close the program" or "check the net for solution", the latter does nothing

Comment: exactly the same result if I try it with the one I had posted earlier

Comment: I cannot tell what the problem is. I suggest you post this information on the [shiny mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shiny-discuss). Make sure to provide your version of Windows (7 or 8?). What browser you use and the output of sessionInfo() from R.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
install.packages('shiny')
```

Comment: `install.packages` also has a `repos` argument that can be used directly, without needing to modify the options

Answer (score -2):

Just stop your firewall and antivirus and then installing the package. It worked for me

Comment: Because it works for you does not neccesarily mean that the ops firewall and antivirus software are interfering.

Comment: Not a generalized answer